# Replace string in Windows Git workflow actions

Tags: string, powershell, replace, environment-variables, github-actions

I wish to replace both characters `\\`  with `/` and `:` with `<blank>` from variable `deploy_path`

```
  - name: Echo server_list
    shell: cmd
    run: echo ${{ steps.dotenv.outputs.deploy_path }}
```

Output:

```
C:\\inetpub\\wwwroot\\soc.qa
```

I'm using Windows 2019 cmd shell. However, I'm fine with a solution using powershell.

I tried the below:

```
  - name: character-replacement-test
    run: newstr=$(echo ${{ steps.dotenv.outputs.deploy_path//[\:]// }})
```

Unfortunately the above does not give me the desired output which is  `C/inetpub/wwwroot/soc.qa`

I would eventually assign the desired output to environment variable `newstr`

I was able to get the powershell to get me the desired output:

```
C:\Users\meuser>powershell (echo 'C:\\inetpub\\wwwroot\\soc.qa') -replace ':','' -replace '\\\\','/'

C/inetpub/wwwroot/soc.qa
```

However, I m not able to incorporate this in Gtihug action `run` step

```
  - name: character-replacement-test

    run: powershell (echo '${ steps.dotenv.outputs.deploy_path }') -replace ':','' -replace '\\\\','/'
```

Output: `shell: C:\Program Files\PowerShell\7\pwsh.EXE -command ". '{0}'"`

Can you please suggest?

Comment: There in no such thing as **batch shell**, and you've offered absolutely no Windows batch file or **cmd.exe** valid code for us to help you to fix. This site does not offer a free code writing service, neither does it walk you through the processes involved in undertaking a laid out programming task.

Comment: @Compo I updated the original post as using `cmd` shell. I m able to achieved the strong manipulation in Unix runner. The challenge is a Windows runner

Comment: What is the error that you're getting for your last step? Here's a working [example](https://rhysd.github.io/actionlint/#eJxNjsEOgjAQRO/9ij2YVBLBexNP/oLHJqSUJaDQxW6xMfHjLWiA0+zOzL4sOQWR/KPpKZZ1x6MJthXiThUrAZB0FgA/Oc5pLneupsh5bwJyEEvIAUf+9QBycGZABTdvHDfkB0jM9h8CoHupdQGocezpXc4VBfKqtO4chnGqtI4xeqKgNZMtnkauV+kXBZ8d5OAwLojLYccrfJqNxaPUWp7kWWabo5Ihsx0CbUsbR3wBWC9SOQ==).

Comment: @Azeem your sample works !! i m not getting any error but I was getting this msg which I had mentioned in the original post -> `Output: shell: C:\Program Files\PowerShell\7\pwsh.EXE -command ". '{0}'"`

Comment: Is that in the logs when the step is expanded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This

```
${ steps.dotenv.outputs.deploy_path }
```

should be

```
${{ steps.dotenv.outputs.deploy_path }}
```

---

In a step, it may simple be like this:

```yaml
name: pwsh_transform_path

on: workflow_dispatch

jobs:
  job:
    runs-on: windows-latest

    steps:
      - name: Transform path
        env:
          deploy_path: '${{ steps.dotenv.outputs.deploy_path }}'
        run: |
          $new_path=$ENV:deploy_path.replace('\\','/').replace(':','')
          echo $new_path
```

Here's an example with hardcoded `deploy_path` as an env var:

[image: output]